# copy table from templates with fixed place using Apache Poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx, xwpf

I have a table in the docx template.
Depending on the number of objects, I have to duplicate the table as many times as I have objects. Duplicate tables must be after the table from the template.
I have several tables in the template that should behave like this.

XmlCursor take the place of the first table from the template and put the next one there. I want to insert the next table after the previous one, which I added myself, but xmlcursor does not return the table item I added, but returns "STARTDOC"

```
XmlCursor cursor = docx.getTables().get(pointer).getCTTbl().newCursor();
cursor.toEndToken();

while (cursor.toNextToken() != XmlCursor.TokenType.START) ;

XWPFParagraph newParagraph = docx.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
newParagraph.createRun().setText("", 0);
cursor.toParent();
cursor.toEndToken();
while (cursor.toNextToken() != XmlCursor.TokenType.START) ;
docx.insertNewTbl(cursor);

CTTbl ctTbl = CTTbl.Factory.newInstance();
ctTbl.set(docx.getTables().get(numberTableFromTemplate).getCTTbl());
XWPFTable tableCopy = new XWPFTable(ctTbl, docx);
docx.setTable(index + 1, tableCopy);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not clear what you are aiming for with the `cursor.toParent();`. And I also cannot reproduce the issue having only your small code snippet. But having a complete working example may possible help you.

Assuming we have following template:

[image]

Then following code:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTbl;

public class WordCopyTableAfterTable {

 static XmlCursor setCursorToNextStartToken(XmlObject object) {
  XmlCursor cursor = object.newCursor();
  cursor.toEndToken(); //Now we are at end of the XmlObject.
  //There always must be a next start token.
  while(cursor.hasNextToken() && cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
  //Now we are at the next start token and can insert new things here.
  return cursor;
 }

 static void removeCellValues(XWPFTableCell cell) {
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
   for (int i = paragraph.getRuns().size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    paragraph.removeRun(i);
   }  
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //The data. Each row a new table.
  String[][] data= new String[][] {
   new String[] {"John Doe", "5/23/2019", "1234.56"},
   new String[] {"Jane Doe", "12/2/2019", "34.56"},
   new String[] {"Marie Template", "9/20/2019", "4.56"},
   new String[] {"Hans Template", "10/2/2019", "4567.89"}
  };

  String value;
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordTemplate.docx"));
  XWPFTable tableTemplate;
  CTTbl cTTblTemplate;
  XWPFTable tableCopy;
  XWPFTable table;
  XWPFTableRow row;
  XWPFTableCell cell;
  XmlCursor cursor;
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;

  //get first table (the template)
  tableTemplate = document.getTableArray(0);
  cTTblTemplate = tableTemplate.getCTTbl();
  cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(cTTblTemplate);

  //fill in first data in first table (the template)
  for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
   value = data[0][c];
   row = tableTemplate.getRow(1);
   cell = row.getCell(c);
   removeCellValues(cell);
   cell.setText(value);
  }

  paragraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor); //insert new empty paragraph
  cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(paragraph.getCTP());

  //fill in next data, each data row in one table
  for (int t = 1; t < data.length; t++) {
   table = document.insertNewTbl(cursor); //insert new empty table at position t
   cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(table.getCTTbl());

   tableCopy = new XWPFTable((CTTbl)cTTblTemplate.copy(), document); //copy the template table

   //fill in data in tableCopy
   for (int c = 0; c < data[t].length; c++) {
    value = data[t][c];
    row = tableCopy.getRow(1);
    cell = row.getCell(c);
    removeCellValues(cell);
    cell.setText(value);
   }
   document.setTable(t, tableCopy); //set tableCopy at position t instead of table

   paragraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor); //insert new empty paragraph
   cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(paragraph.getCTP());
  }

  paragraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
  run = paragraph.createRun(); 
  run.setText("Inserted new text below last table.");
  cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(paragraph.getCTP());

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordResult.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

leads to following result:

[image]

Is that about what you wanted to achieve?

Please note how I insert the additional tables.

Using `table = document.insertNewTbl(cursor);`  a new empty table is inserted at position `t`. This table is placed into the document body. So this table must be taken for adjusting the cursor.

Then `tableCopy = new XWPFTable((CTTbl)cTTblTemplate.copy(), document);` copys the template table. Then this copy is filled with data. And then it is set into the document at position `t` using `document.setTable(t, tableCopy);`.

Unfortunately `apache poi` is incomplete here. `XWPFDocument.setTable` only sets the internally `ArrayList`s but not the underlying `XML`. `XWPFDocument.insertNewTbl` sets the underlying `XML` but only using an empty table. So we must do it that ugly complicated way.