# How can I duplicate a table in word with apache poi?

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I have an entity Service that has a few properties. Now I want to create a table for every Service I have in a List. I currently have a placeholder table in there where I copy the right amount of rows but before that I need to create all the necessary tables based on the placeholder table and have a header for each table.

So with document.getTables() I can get the tables but how do I add tables to the correct place with a header for each table (not an additional table row but a header outside the table)?

Comment: Something like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014683/copy-table-from-templates-with-fixed-place-using-apache-poi/58026015#58026015?

Comment: If this is not a duplicate, please [edit] your question to include a [mre] that shows your revised approach.

Comment: @AxelRichter Yes, thank you. Now I additionally need to have headers for each table. Is it also possible that way? Where would I need to edit the code?