# Apache POI accessing tables in a XWPFDocument returns only first table

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to put every single row from `JTable (xlTab, 3 columns)` in its own page in `XWPFDocument` (If rows=10, then pages=10, one row in each page). I have an external template `.DOCX` file ready and this action will be performed on the document itself. The code is:

```java
File file = JFileChooser1.getSelectedFile();
XWPFDocument order=new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));
CTBody page=order.getDocument().getBody();
                
XWPFTable table;

for(int x=0;x<xlTab.getRowCount();x++){
    table=order.getTableArray(x);
    System.out.println("Tables present: "+table.toString());
    for(int col=0;col<3;col++){
        table.getRow(0).getCell(col).setText(xlTab.getColumnName(col)+":\n"+xlTab.getValueAt(x,col));
    }
    order.getDocument().AddNewBody().set(page);
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Tables present: org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFTable@3c1e93f9
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
```

Why does `table` contain only one Table?

Edit: I'm using Java 18, and the above code is executed on a button click (for nitpickers).

Comment: The code is compiling successfully. Did you name your `JTable` as `XLTab`? populate it with some data?

I'm aware that `getTableArray(int pos)` returns one `XWPFTable`, which I'm selecting through index `x`.

Since I'm adding new `Body` at the end of the loop, which already has a table (evident by it getting selected by index 0), the count of `XWPFTable` should increase by one after each loop.

Comment: "Since I'm adding new Body ... the count of XWPFTable should increase by one after each loop.": That will not happen. Simply adding multiple `CTBody` elements one after the other is not how a Word document is structured. A Word document contains **one** text body which contains all content, inclusive tables. And btw.: A `CTBody` may contain multiple pages. So calling it `page` is misleading.

Comment: Oh I see. I mistyped the code. It's not `List<XWPFTable> table` but `WXPFTable table` in my source code. I'll edit the question's code.

Comment: Also, how do you suggest I add a new page and access its table? Currently I'm saving this docx first and then re-loading it. But I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: There was questions about copying and fill table templates in an existing Word document already. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014683/copy-table-from-templates-with-fixed-place-using-apache-poi/58026015#58026015 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73497600/insert-varying-amount-of-headings-and-tables-with-apache-poi/73500394#73500394.

Comment: To add page breaks there is [XWPFParagraph.setPageBreak](/https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFParagraph.html#setPageBreak-boolean-) or [XWPFRun.addBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addBreak-org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.BreakType-) - [BreakType.PAGE](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/BreakType.html#PAGE).

Comment: Are you trying to imply that I have to insert each table and text into the next new page programmatically in order for `XWPFTable` to access it? But the caveat is the template is subject to change (there will be exactly one table, but other contents will change depending on the situation). Is there any `copy` method similar to `Range.copy()` in VB through which I can copy the template irrespective of its contents?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creating table through `CTTbl` resolves this issue:

```java
JFileChooser fc=new JFileChooser();
XWPFDocument template=new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));    //This is the template file
XWPFDocument intermediate=new XWPFDocument();    //all the changes will be done in this file. Directly modifying template will throw ConcurrentModificationException

CTTbl tbl=CTTbl.Factory.newInstance();
tbl.set(template.getTables().get(0).getCTTbl());    //template contains only one table.
int pos=0;

for(int i=0;i<xlTab.getRowCount();i++){
    for(IBodyElement ele:template.getBodyElements()){
        switch(ele.getElementType()){
            case PARAGRAPH -> {
                intermediate.createParagraph();
                intermediate.setParagraph((XWPFParagraph)ele,pos++);
            }
            case TABLE -> {
                intermediate.createTable();
            }
            case 
        }
    }
    intermediate.createParagraph().createRun().addBreak(BreakType.PAGE);
    pos++;
}
XWPFTable tempTab = new XWPFTable(tbl, intermediate);
//
//Add items to tempTab here
//
intermediate.setTable(i,tempTab);
```