# Insert varying amount of headings and tables with apache poi

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I want to insert a varying amount of text into a word document. E.g.

```
Heading 1
  Subheading 1
    Table 1
  Subheading 2
    Table 2
```

I used a cursor after finding the right spot in the word document, but don't know how I can create multiple stuff at that position. I got it to work with a single paragraph with text. I also tried using a for-loop after the while-statement but the createRun method referenced a paragraph that is null and therefore threw an error.

```
XmlCursor cursor = table.getCTTbl().newCursor();
cursor.toEndToken();
while (cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
    XWPFParagraph newParagraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor);
    XWPFRun run = newParagraph.createRun();
    run.setText("inserted new text " + "\n");
```

Comment: The `XmlCursor` needs to be created on the correct position in document. So how exactly are you determining the "the right spot in the word document"? What exactly is marking that spot?

Answer (score 2):

The `XmlCursor` needs to be created on the correct position in document. That must not be a position, which is not before a start token. And that must not be a position inside any other body element which cannot contain a paragraph or a table.

To adjust the cursor properly before a start token, following method cn be used:

```
 /*modifiers*/ XmlCursor setCursorToNextStartToken(XmlObject object) {
  XmlCursor cursor = object.newCursor();
  cursor.toEndToken(); //Now we are at end of the XmlObject.
  //There always must be a next start token.
  while(cursor.hasNextToken() && cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
  //Now we are at the next start token and can insert new things here.
  return cursor;
 }
```

But the `XmlObject object` needs to be an body element which is at a position of the text body which allows to add a paragraph or a table.

Let`s have a complete example again:

If WordTemplate.docx looks like...

[image]

...then following code

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlObject;
import org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTTbl;

public class WordCopyTableAfterTable {

 static XmlCursor setCursorToNextStartToken(XmlObject object) {
  XmlCursor cursor = object.newCursor();
  cursor.toEndToken(); //Now we are at end of the XmlObject.
  //There always must be a next start token.
  while(cursor.hasNextToken() && cursor.toNextToken() != org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlCursor.TokenType.START);
  //Now we are at the next start token and can insert new things here.
  return cursor;
 }

 static void removeCellValues(XWPFTableCell cell) {
  for (XWPFParagraph paragraph : cell.getParagraphs()) {
   for (int i = paragraph.getRuns().size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    paragraph.removeRun(i);
   }  
  }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  //The data. Each row a new table.
  String[][] data= new String[][] {
   new String[] {"John Doe", "5/23/2019", "1234.56"},
   new String[] {"Jane Doe", "12/2/2019", "34.56"},
   new String[] {"Marie Template", "9/20/2019", "4.56"},
   new String[] {"Hans Template", "10/2/2019", "4567.89"}
  };

  String value;
  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream("WordTemplate.docx"));
  XWPFTable tableTemplate;
  CTTbl cTTblTemplate;
  XWPFTable tableCopy;
  XWPFTable table;
  XWPFTableRow row;
  XWPFTableCell cell;
  XmlCursor cursor;
  XWPFParagraph paragraph;
  XWPFRun run;
  
  // get Heading 2 style
  XWPFStyles styles = document.getStyles();
  XWPFStyle style = styles.getStyleWithName("Heading 2"); if (style == null) style = styles.getStyleWithName("heading 2");
  String heading2StyleId = (style != null)?style.getStyleId():"";
  
  //get first table (the template)
  tableTemplate = document.getTableArray(0);
  cTTblTemplate = tableTemplate.getCTTbl();
  cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(cTTblTemplate);

  //fill in first data in first table (the template)
  for (int c = 0; c < data[0].length; c++) {
   value = data[0][c];
   row = tableTemplate.getRow(1);
   cell = row.getCell(c);
   removeCellValues(cell);
   cell.setText(value);
  }

  paragraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor); //insert new empty paragraph
  cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(paragraph.getCTP());

  //fill in next data, each data row in one table
  for (int t = 1; t < data.length; t++) {
   paragraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor); //insert new empty paragraph
   paragraph.setStyle(heading2StyleId); //style it Heading 2
   run = paragraph.createRun(); 
   run.setText("Subheading " + (t+1));
   cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(paragraph.getCTP());
     
   table = document.insertNewTbl(cursor); //insert new empty table at position t
   cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(table.getCTTbl());

   tableCopy = new XWPFTable((CTTbl)cTTblTemplate.copy(), document); //copy the template table

   //fill in data in tableCopy
   for (int c = 0; c < data[t].length; c++) {
    value = data[t][c];
    row = tableCopy.getRow(1);
    cell = row.getCell(c);
    removeCellValues(cell);
    cell.setText(value);
   }
   document.setTable(t, tableCopy); //set tableCopy at position t instead of table

   paragraph = document.insertNewParagraph(cursor); //insert new empty paragraph
   cursor = setCursorToNextStartToken(paragraph.getCTP());
  }

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("WordResult.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();
 }
}
```

...produces following  `WordResult.docx`.

[image]