How to Copy a Varying Column Per Row Table and Place It Below the Original in a DOCX File Using Apache POI?
I am working with Apache POI to manipulate DOCX files and need to perform a specific task involving tables. I have a table in a DOCX file where each row has a varying number of columns. My goal is to copy each row from this table and append it as a new table below the original one, preserving the varying column structure as well as cell styling.
Here is the code I have, it currently just copies the text but does not maintain cell span, style or format.
XWPFTable frTable = document.getTables().get(1);
XWPFTable newTable = document.createTable();
for (int i = 0; i < frTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
    XWPFTableRow originalRow = frTable.getRow(i);
    XWPFTableRow newRow = newTable.createRow();
            
    // Iterate over cells
    for (int j = 0; j < originalRow.getTableCells().size(); j++) {
        XWPFTableCell originalCell = originalRow.getCell(j);
        XWPFTableCell newCell = newRow.getCell(j);
                
        if (newCell == null) {
            newCell = newRow.addNewTableCell();
        }
        // Copy cell content
        newCell.setText(originalCell.getText());
     }
}
newTable.removeRow(0);

Here is the original table for reference:
Reference Table

Why not copying the whole table then? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014683/copy-table-from-templates-with-fixed-place-using-apache-poi/58026015#58026015. Just tested. Works using more complex tables too.
