How to Insert a New Table Immediately After an Existing Table in a DOCX Document Using Apache POI?
I am using Apache POI to manipulate DOCX documents in Java. I have an existing table in my document and I need to insert a new table immediately after this existing table. However, when I create the new table, it is being added at the end of the document instead of right after the original table.
        XWPFTable frTable = document.getTables().get(0);
        XWPFTable newTable = document.createTable(frTable.getNumberOfRows(), frTable.getRow(0).getTableCells().size());

        // Copy each row
        for (int i = 0; i < frTable.getNumberOfRows(); i++) {
            XWPFTableRow srcRow = frTable.getRow(i);
            XWPFTableRow destRow = newTable.getRow(i);

            // Copy each cell
            for (int j = 0; j < srcRow.getTableCells().size(); j++) {
                XWPFTableCell srcCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
                XWPFTableCell destCell = destRow.getCell(j);

                // Copy cell text
                destCell.setText(srcCell.getText());

                // Copy cell styles
                copyCellStyles(srcCell, destCell);
            }
        }

Here is my code for the table creation and duplication, ive tried adding after the index that the table appears with no luck. If I understand apache-poi paragraph and table indexes are different and dont communicate with eachother. For this I also tried to look into the body() functions of apache poi but that didnt work either.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58014683/copy-table-from-templates-with-fixed-place-using-apache-poi/58026015#58026015 for how to insert a table at a special position using XWPFDocument.insertNewTbl(XmlCursor). Additional reads: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a3915431%20%2AinsertNewTbl%2A&searchOn=3
